# Кроссдоменый ajax не работает

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Не могу вставить в таблицу данные, отправляя с другого сервера. Выдается ошибка:

> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.

**Посылаю данные (JS файл на сервере 1):**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://bla.com/conect.php",
  data: { email: email }
})
```

**На сервере 2:**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); //Попытка разрешить кроссдоменные запросы)

$email = $_GET['email'];

$con = mysqli_connect('bla','bla','bla','bla');

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO sinc (data) VALUES ('$email')");
```

Comment: сервер 2 формирует header програмно? Если да - то до скрипта может дело не дойти...

Comment: mod_headers в httpd.conf энаблед?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было добавить в .htaccess
    
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, content-    type"